# Does performance suffer if I attach .on('click' events to $("body")?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have the following code:

```
$('#loginLink, #registerLink').click(function () {
        dialog(this);
        return false;
    });

$('#detailData')
    .on('click', '.modalDeleteLink, .modalEditLink', function () {
        dialog(this);
        return false;
    })
```

There are just one of #loginLink and #registerLink but there could be up to a hundred elements with the classes .modalDeleteLink and .modalEditLink.

I was thinking to change all of these elements so they have a class of .dialogLink and then just using the following code:

```
$("body").on("click", ".dialogLink", function(){
   dialog(this);
   return false;
});
```

This code is a lot easier to maintain. However would there be any performance disadvantage in attaching this to the body?

Comment: Why not `$(".dialogLink").on("click", function(){
   dialog(this);
   return false;
});`

Comment: @jacktheripper's got the answer. That'll be your most efficent solution. It'll use the CSS selectors. Can I also suggest $(".dialogLink").click(function(){ dialog(this); return false; });

Comment: @jacktheripper Why would multiple event handlers for each `.dialogLink` be better than delegating the event to the `body`?

Comment: Wait I cannot do $(".dialogLink") because there are things on my page that are added later? I need to pick something on my HTML that's there from the start.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to worry about performance, unless you have hundreds of handlers or extremely large document.

Extract from [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

In most cases, an **event such as click occurs infrequently and performance is not a significant concern**. However, high frequency events such as mousemove or scroll can fire dozens of times per second, and in those cases it becomes more important to use events judiciously. Performance can be increased by reducing the amount of work done in the handler itself, caching information needed by the handler rather than recalculating it, or by rate-limiting the number of actual page updates using setTimeout.

Attaching **many delegated event handlers near the top of the document tree can degrade performance**. Each time the event occurs, jQuery must compare all selectors of all attached events of that type to every element in the path from the event target up to the top of the document. For best performance, attach delegated events at a document location as close as possible to the target elements. Avoid excessive use of document or document.body for delegated events on large documents.

Comment: What if there are thousands of click event, say for a comment section a la reddit with upvotes and downvotes. The problem is that each comment node is quite big.

Answer (score 4):

In jQuery, the higher up you place the .on() in the DOM, the slower it will be. This is because jQuery must compare all selectors of all attached events of the selected type from the  target to the document level.

See [the jQuery documentation page for .on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> Attaching many delegated event handlers near the top of the document tree can degrade
>   performance. Each time the event occurs, jQuery must compare all selectors of all
>   attached events of that type to every element in the path from the event target up to the
>   top of the document. For best performance, attach delegated events at a document location
>   as close as possible to the target elements. Avoid excessive use of document or
>   document.body for delegated events on large documents.

With this being said, the performance difference may likely be negligible for click events since, unlike scrolling or mouse movement events, they fire infrequently (only on the user's click).

Comment: To register a delegate event, one needs to pass a selector as a parameter to .on ( ) method. Only if .on( ) method is used to register delegate events, does the performance of the page suffer -- since in that case events on child element need to be bubbled up and checked against the selector. If .on( ) is used to only attach an event on an element (non-delegate mode), then it should have no performance impact - even if its on the body.

Comment: That is true, and why the documentation specifies delegated events. Direct events don't need to do all of the comparison/selector work and will outperform delegated events in the general case.

Though, I doubt the OP will have not discovered this after almost three years. :)